# How to auto detect text file encoding?

Tags: linux, batch, encoding

There are many plain text files which were encoded in variant charsets.

I want to convert them all to UTF-8, but before running iconv, I need to know its original encoding. Most browsers have an `Auto Detect` option in encodings, however, I can't check those text files one by one because there are too many.

Only having known the original encoding, I then can convert the texts by `iconv -f DETECTED_CHARSET -t utf-8`.

Is there any utility to detect the encoding of plain text files? It DOES NOT have to be 100% perfect, I don't mind if there're 100 files misconverted in 1,000,000 files.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try the [chardet](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) Python module, which is available on PyPI:

```
pip install chardet
```

Then run `chardetect myfile.txt`.

Chardet is based on the [detection code](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html) used by Mozilla, so it should give reasonable results, provided that the input text is long enough for statistical analysis. Do read the [project documentation](http://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

As mentioned in comments it is quite slow, but some distributions also ship the original C++ version as @Xavier has found in https://superuser.com/a/609056. There is also a Java version somewhere.

Comment: Yes, and it's already packaged as `python-chardet` in Ubuntu universe repo.

Comment: If it wasn't a perfect guess, `chardet` will still give the most correctly guess, like `./a.txt: GB2312 (confidence: 0.99)`. Compared to Enca which just failed and report 'Unrecognized encoding'. However, sadly enough, `chardet` runs very slow.

Comment: @谢继雷: Have it run overnight or something like that. Charset detection *is* a [complicated process](http://chardet.feedparser.org/docs/faq.html). You could also try the Java-based jChardet or ... the original *chardet* is [part of Mozilla](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/chardet.html), but only C++ source is available, no command-line tool.

Comment: Regarding speed: running `chardet <(head -c4000 filename.txt)` was much faster and equally successful for my use-case. (in case it's not clear this bash syntax will send only the first 4000 bytes to chardet)

Comment: @ndemou I have `chardet==3.0.4`, and the command line tool's actual executable name is `chardetect` not `chardet`.

Comment: It's not very precise, unfortunately. I tested it with several subtitle files in different languages but it's not reliable. It gets many encodings wrong...

Answer (score 42):

I would use this simple command:

```
encoding=$(file -bi myfile.txt)
```

Or if you want just the actual character set (like `utf-8`):

```
encoding=$(file -b --mime-encoding myfile.txt)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `file` only detects encodings with specific properties, such as UTF-8 or UTF-16. The rest -- oldish ISO8859 or their MS-DOS and Windows correspondents -- are listed as "unknown-8bit" or something similar, even for files which `chardet` detects with 99% confidence.

Comment: file showed me iso-8859-1

Comment: What if the extension is lying?

Comment: @james.garriss: file extension has nothing to do with its (text) content encoding.

Comment: In case some noob like me gets confused as to how to retrieve the value that we're storing in "encoding", simply type: "echo $encoding".
Alternatively, you can use the part inside the parentheses by itself, without storing any variables: "file -bi myfile.txt".

Answer (score 34):

On Debian-based Linux, the [uchardet](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/uchardet/uchardet) package ([Debian](https://packages.qa.debian.org/u/uchardet.html) / [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/uchardet)) provides a command line tool.  See below the package description:

```
 universal charset detection library - cli utility
 .
 uchardet is a C language binding of the original C++ implementation
 of the universal charset detection library by Mozilla.
 .
 uchardet is a encoding detector library, which takes a sequence of
 bytes in an unknown character encoding without any additional
 information, and attempts to determine the encoding of the text.
 .
 The original code of universalchardet is available at
 http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/extensions/universalchardet
 .
 Techniques used by universalchardet are described at
 http://www.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html
```

Comment: Thanks! From the project's homepage it wasn't obvious to me that there was a CLI included. It's also available on OS X when installing `uchardet` via Homebrew.

Comment: I was a little confused at first because a ISO 8859-1 document was falsely identified as Windows-1252 but in the printable range Windows-1252 is a superset of ISO 8859-1 so conversion with `iconv` works fine.

Comment: Hi @StefanSchmidt, *charset detection* is based on *corpus* statistics. In countries like Brazil the old official standard encode (before UTF8) was  ISO-8859-1... But it is a "Microsoft country", so the most popular in any statistics is the Microsoft's distortion of ISO (against competition), that is  Windows-1252. It is a side effect of the technological colonialism in a country: weak sovereignty, weak official standards and strong Microsoft lobbying. Even now (2021 is [1 decade after universal adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Adoption)!) it is dominant in TXT and CSV files.

Answer (score 17):

For Linux, there is [enca](https://github.com/nijel/enca) and for Solaris you can use [auto_ef](http://developers.sun.com/global/technology/standards/reference/faqs/determining-file-encoding.html).

Comment: Enca seems too strict for me: `enca -d -L zh ./a.txt` failed with message `./a.txt: Unrecognized encoding Failure reason: No clear winner.` As @grawity mentioned, `chardet` is more lax, however it's yet too slow.

Comment: Enca completely fails the "actually does something" test.

Comment: uchardet failed (detected CP1252 instead of the actual CP1250), but enca worked fine.  (single example, hard to generalize...)

Answer (score 3):

For those regularly using Emacs, they might find the following useful (allows to inspect and validate manually the transfomation).

Moreover I often find that the Emacs char-set auto-detection is much more efficient than the other char-set auto-detection tools (such as chardet).

```
(setq paths (mapcar 'file-truename '(
 "path/to/file1"
 "path/to/file2"
 "path/to/file3"
)))

(dolist (path paths)
  (find-file path)
  (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
  )
```

Then, a simple call to Emacs with this script as argument (see the "-l" option) does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Mozilla has a nice codebase for auto-detection in web pages:
http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/extensions/universalchardet/src/

Detailed description of the algorithm:
http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html

Answer (score 2):

Getting back to chardet (python 2.?) this call might be enough:

```
python -c 'import chardet,sys; print chardet.detect(sys.stdin.read())' < file
{'confidence': 0.98999999999999999, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

Though it's far from perfect....

```
echo "öasd" | iconv -t ISO-8859-1 | python -c 'import chardet,sys; print chardet.detect(sys.stdin.read())'
{'confidence': 0.5, 'encoding': 'windows-1252'}
```

Answer (score 1):

UTFCast is worth a try. Didn't work for me (maybe because my files are terrible) but it looks good.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-batch-convert-text-files-to-utf-8-encoding/

Answer (score 1):

`isutf8` (from the `moreutils` package) did the job

Comment: How? This answer isn't really helpful.

Comment: It's not exactly was asked, but is a useful tool.
If the file is valid UTF-8, the exit status is zero.  If the file is not valid UTF-8, or there is some error, the exit status is non-zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you're unhappy with *chardet* like I am because it doesn't properly recognize some encodings, try out [detect-file-encoding-and-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language). I've found it to be a lot more reliable than *chardet*.

**1. Make sure you have Node.js and NPM installed. You can install them like this:**

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

**2. Install [detect-file-encoding-and-language](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-file-encoding-and-language):**

```bsh
$ npm install -g detect-file-encoding-and-language
```

**3. Now you can use it to detect the encoding:**

```bsh
$ dfeal "/home/user name/Documents/subtitle file.srt"
```

It'll return an object with the detected encoding, language, and a confidence score.

Answer (score 0):

Also in case you file -i gives you unknown

You can use this php command that can guess charset like below :

In php you can check like below :

Specifying encoding list explicitly :

```
php -r "echo 'probably : ' . mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents('myfile.txt'), 'UTF-8, ASCII, JIS, EUC-JP, SJIS, iso-8859-1') . PHP_EOL;"
```

More accurate "**mb_list_encodings**":

```
php -r "echo 'probably : ' . mb_detect_encoding(file_get_contents('myfile.txt'), mb_list_encodings()) . PHP_EOL;"
```

Here in first example, you can see that i put a list of encodings (detect list order) that might be matching.
To have more accurate result you can use all possible encodings via : *mb_list_encodings()*

Note mb_* functions require php-mbstring

```
apt-get install php-mbstring
```

See answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57010566/3382822